# Combining 'words/parts' to make a 'whole/string'?

Tags: python, permutation

Let say I have a pseudo-words of different length . f.e. :  a,b,r,c,brac, rac,ab, ra, bra,ca,dabr, abr, ...

Let say currently i have a string for matching :  abrac

I can match it in different ways : a:brac, a:bra:c, ab:ra:c, a:bra:c, a:b:rac, a:b:r:a:c, ab:rac, ...

What is a cheap and fast way to generate all possible permutations of combining the 'blocks' to generate the required 'string'

Current thoughts of the top :

```
blocks = [ w for w in words if w in string ]
perms =  [ [ c for c in [':'.join(lst) for lst in permutations(blocks,N)] if string == c.replace(':','') ] for N in [2,3,4] ]

: [['a:brac', 'ab:rac'], ['a:b:rac', 'a:bra:c', 'ab:ra:c', 'abr:a:c'], ['a:b:ra:c', 'ab:r:a:c']]
```

> N is unknown, plus must be 2,3,4... ? Possibly too many combinations are generated i.e. it is slow i.e. generation have to be controlled somehow !

My final goal is to pick the combination with least number of 'blocks' with the longest 'blocks'.
But you can skip that for now if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for a recursive function that adds suffixes onto the end of the candidate. Prune candidates that are too long or don't prefix-match the string, so it won't grow out of control. If you try to generate all the permutations first, it will be too slow, as you found.

In a bit more detail, the recursive function takes the current prefix string and a list of the blocks used to create it. It then tries appending each block, and calling itself recursively. When it finds a match, print the blocks used.

I implemented this in a few lines and it generates the results instantaneously.

For your final goal of using the fewest blocks, you could use a breadth-first search instead. Generate all the 1-block strings. Then add all potential blocks to each of those to generate 2-block strings. Repeat as needed until you get the desired string. At each step, discard strings that aren't a prefix of the desired string so it won't grow out of control.